# How can I display posts side by side?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I created the WordPress loop below to display posts from a certain category in a row side by side. I'm having trouble because they are displayed on top of each other. I'm using Bootstrap 4

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'category_name'     => 'featured',
        'posts_per_page'    => 4
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

    ?>

    <?php if($the_query->have_posts()): while($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="row featured-row">

        <div class="col-md-3">

        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'fimage', array('class' => 'img-fluid') ); ?>
        <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
        <em>Posted on - <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></em>
        <em>Written by - <?php the_author(); ?></em>

        </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these :

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'category_name'     => 'featured',
        'posts_per_page'    => 4
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

    ?>
<?php if($the_query->have_posts()): ?>
    <div class="row featured-row">
        <?php while($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'fimage', array('class' => 'img-fluid') ); ?>
                <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                <em>Posted on - <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></em>
                <em>Written by - <?php the_author(); ?></em>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your div with class row outside the loop.  Use below code

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'category_name'     => 'featured',
        'posts_per_page'    => 4
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if($the_query->have_posts()):
    echo '  <div class="row featured-row">';
    while($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'fimage', array('class' => 'img-fluid') ); ?>
        <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
        <em>Posted on - <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></em>
        <em>Written by - <?php the_author(); ?></em>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; 
echo '</div>';        
 endif; ?>
        <hr>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```